# How to match multiple capture groups with str_match(..., regex)

Tags: r, regex, string-matching, capture, stringr

I am using `str_match` from the `stringr` package to capture text in between brackets.

```
library(stringr)

strs = c("P5P (abcde) + P5P (fghij)", "Glcext (abcdef)")
str_match(strs, "\\(([a-z]+)\\)")
```

gives me only the matches `"abcde"` and `"abcdef"`. How can I capture the `"fghij"` as well with still using the same regex for both strings?

Comment: Does `str_match_all(strs, "\\(([a-z]+)\\)")` do what you're wanting?

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! i did not know about it cause it was not linked in the "See Also:" section in the help page...

Comment: That *would* be a good addition to the help file. In my experience, it's often worth trying something like this to see what else is available: `ls("package:stringr")`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
str_extract_all(strs, "\\(([a-z]+)\\)")
```

or as @JoshO'Brien mentions in his comment,

```
str_match_all(strs, "\\(([a-z]+)\\)")
```

This can just as easily be accomplished with base R:

```
regmatches(strs, gregexpr("\\(([a-z]+)\\)", strs))
```

Comment: Works well, thanks. But why is it that with the 'regmatches' the brackets are also captured?

Comment: `str_match_all` returns both matches and groups within your matches. `str_extract_all` and `regmatches`/`gregexpr` return just the matches. If you want these last to methods to return just what's instead the `()`, use `pat = "(?<=\\()[a-z]+(?=\\))"` with `str_extract_all(strs, perl(pat))` or `regmatches(strs, gregexpr(pat, strs, perl=TRUE))`. This pattern uses look ahead and behind assertions. See the end of the Perl section in `?regex` for more details on whats going on here.